# Avoiding “is that” when adding an explanatory subordinate clause to a sentence in academic writing

Tags: grammar, phrases

Consider the following sentence as a starter of the final paragraph of an article:

> While previous studies have proven to be valuable, a potential drawback of the type of methods used **is that** they evaluate . . ..

When I read that sentence out loud, it sounds a bit “clumpy” perhaps even a bit informal. Is there better way to phrase such a sentence? Alternatively, am I worried for no reason here?

Comment: I vote for worried without reason.

Comment: I assume *clumpy* was intended to be read as *clunky*. Right?

Comment: @tchrist yep, see the comment to StoneyB's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem here is with *they evaluate*.

Presumably, it refers to *methods*, since that is the only plural antecedent in that clause. But consider what it looks like when you shuffle the pieces around:

> The type of methods used evaluate X.

The subject of this clause is *type*, not *methods*, and it requires a singular verb.

What you want to say is:

> ... a potential drawback with methods of the type used is that they evaluate ...

I've changed *drawback of* to *drawback with* to avoid two *ofs* that close to each other, but that's just for my ear: it's not essential.

Finally, I think the word you want is *clunky*, 'mechanically awkward', not *clumpy*, 'composed of clumps'.

Comment: Thanks, "clumpy" is a swenglish invention that unfortunately got away when I was trying to formulate my concern with the way I formulated the sentence in the OP. Oh and I actually did not use "they" but instead "these methods" in the actual text, the real sentence is pretty long and technical so I tried to simplify it a bit when I posted here :)

Comment: _Clumpy_ is an ordinary adjective formed from _clump_. _He wouldn't go down the slope with me; he said it looked too clumpy down there and he was afraid he wouldn't be able to get through._ Perfectly coherent in meaning with other [KL- words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/kl-chart.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler Fersher it's a legit word. I said as much. But I don't think it's the word he meant.

Comment: @StoneyB: Sorry, missed that. But it's still in the same phonosemantic ballpark as _clunky_, as well as being close phonetically.

Comment: for what it's worth, the swedish word *klumpig* usually means "clumsy" and/or "awkward" (see: http://folkets-lexikon.csc.kth.se/folkets/#lookup&klumpig&0) which is what I was aiming for in the OP.

Comment: @posdef *Clumpy* is used in that sense of things like shoes; *lumpish* is used of dull awkward people. *Clunky* is in origin onomatopoeic, like a slow engine or drive train with a loose bearing.

Comment: _Clump_ and _clunk_ are doubly phonosemantic, since the rimes _[-ump](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/-ump.pdf)_ and _[-unk](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/-unk.pdf)_ are also coherent. In particular, an "ump" is a 3-dimensional thing of roughly equal size in all three dimensions. So a _clump_ is an "ump" made up of other things put together (i.e, a "kl"). A _clunk_, on the other hand is usually a noise, and not a happy noise, often things banging together audibly. So anything _clunky_ is something capable of malfunctioning, like an engine or a construction.

Comment: @JohnLawler  Which explains why we say *KiLL the UMP*  - because he's traditionally a three-dimensional being of roughly equal sizes in all dimensions who frequently malfunctions, audibly.

Comment: You bet. Calling a human an "ump" or an "unk" is not a compliment.